# .htaccess rewrite multiple urls in the same folder

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to rewrite some URLs but because I'm kind of a `.htaccess` fresher, I have no idea how to make it myself.

So far I have: `example.com/page/AAA0001/?id=78324#78324` now the page is loading from `AAA0001/index.php`, I need what ever folder name ex: `AAA0001` or `AAA0002` `index.php` should serve from `example.com/page/index.php`, but the above URL should not change (eg. `example.com/page/AAA0001/?id=78324#78324`)

How can I do this using `.htaccess`?

Comment: "now the page is loading from AAA0001/index.php" - why does `/page/AAA0001/index.php` exist?

Answer (score 0):

> now the page is loading from `AAA0001/index.php`

So `AAA0001` is a physical "directory" on the filesystem, not simply a (virtual) URL-path segment. (But then why does `/page/AAA0001/index.php` exist to begin with?)

The `DirectoryIndex` directive (part of mod_dir) determines what file Apache tries to serve when requesting a directory.

Currently, this is probably set to something like `DirectoryIndex index.php` (a relative URL-path), so this tries to serve `index.php` from whatever directory is requested.

However, you can set this to a root-relative URL-path so it will always serve a specific file when a directory is requested. For example:

```
DirectoryIndex /page/index.php
```

Now, when you request a URL like `example.com/page/AAA0001/?id=78324#78324` (where `/page/AAA0001` is a physical directory) it will serve `/page/index.php` instead of `/page/AAA0001/index.php`.

You can also set both, so that it will serve `index.php` in the requested directory if it exists, otherwise *fallback* to `/page/index.php`:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php /page/index.php
```

Reference:

- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindex

---

On the other hand, if this should only apply to requests of the form `/page/ABC01234/` (where the directory consists of 3 uppercase letters followed by 4 digits - as per your examples) then you can combine the `DirectoryIndex` directive with an `<If>` expression. For example:

```
<If "%{REQUEST_URI} =~ m#^/page/[A-Z]{3}\d{4}/#">
    DirectoryIndex /page/index.php
</If>
```

---

Alternatively, use mod_rewrite instead:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^page/[A-Z]{3}\d{4}/ page/index.php [L]
```

The preceding *condition* (`RewriteCond` directive) is perhaps unnecessary, but this ensures that only requests for physical directories are rewritten to `/page/index.php` and not `/page/ZZZ9999/` that may not exist. This mimics the behaviour of `DirectoryIndex` as mentioned above.

Comment: Thanks MrWhite you solution executed successfully.

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^page/[A-Z]{3}\d{4}/ page/index.php [L]

Comment: @MujeebullRahaman You're welcome. If this answered your question then please mark it as "accepted" by clicking the tick/checkmark next to the answer (to help other readers and to remove the question from the unanswered question queue). Once you have 15 rep you can also upvote answers that you find helpful. Thanks, much appreciated. :)